# Why do some flip flops have control inputs? In what ways do they differ from the normal inputs such as J and K?

Tags: clock, flipflop, input, circuits, sequential-logic

I'm currently studying sequential circuits and came across this question. Can't figute out the answer. Can somebody help?

Comment: J and K are "control inputs" so, what is your real question?

Comment: Welcome. Please help us out and post schematics of what concerns you. What is normal depends on what is needed.

Comment: As Andy said, J/K can be considered control inputs. So there is a different definition used in the lecture or textbook, and that question wants you to parrot that definition. Asking here will not help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most basic element is a D flip-flop which performs a simple latch-data-on-active-clock-edge task. Others like JK and T flip-flops can be constructed from D flip-flop plus some combinational logic. Though technically library vendors can provide standard cells like JK flip-flops, I can't remember whether I have ever seen such a cell in my work.